# Mudar o local de salvamento de um PDF em Python (pdf.save())

Tags: python

Fiz um programa em Python que no final gera um PDF com os seguintes dados:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

    pdf = canvas.Canvas("vendas_produtos.pdf")
    pdf.setFont("Times-Bold", 14)
    pdf.drawString(200, 800, "Produtos vendidos:")
    pdf.setFont("Times-Bold", 10)

    pdf.drawString(10, 750, "ID")
    pdf.drawString(60, 750, "Descrição")
    pdf.drawString(230, 750, "Preço")
    pdf.drawString(310, 750, "Dia")
    pdf.drawString(340, 750, "Mês")
    pdf.drawString(370, 750, "Quant.")
    pdf.drawString(420, 750, "L. u.(%)")
    pdf.drawString(470, 750, "L. u.(R$)")
    pdf.drawString(520, 750, "L. Tot.(R$)")
    pdf.drawString(400, 800, "Lucro Total:")
    pdf.drawString(470, 800, f"{moeda(lucro_total)}")

    for i in range(0, len(gerar_pdf_dados)):
        y += 50
        pdf.drawString(10, 750 - y, str(gerar_pdf_dados[i][0]))
        pdf.drawString(60, 750 - y, str(gerar_pdf_dados[i][1]))
        pdf.drawString(230, 750 - y, str(gerar_pdf_dados[i][2]))
        pdf.drawString(310, 750 - y, str(gerar_pdf_dados[i][3]))
        pdf.drawString(340, 750 - y, str(gerar_pdf_dados[i][4]))
        pdf.drawString(370, 750 - y, str(gerar_pdf_dados[i][5]))
        pdf.drawString(420, 750 - y, str(gerar_pdf_dados[i][6]))
        pdf.drawString(470, 750 - y, str(gerar_pdf_dados[i][7]))
        pdf.drawString(520, 750 - y, str(gerar_pdf_dados[i][8]))
    pdf.save()
```

Queria salvar esse arquivo na área de trabalho e não na pasta do programa, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: é só salvar nessa pasta e utilizar `copy` e enviar para qualquer outra pasta, já tentou isso, pelo visto esse método pelo que eu vi na Internet só faz isso

Comment: É porque quando eu transformo o programa em .exe da erro ao gerar o pdf, por isso queria colocar um comando pra salvar na área de trabalho, entendeu?

Comment: Mais ai é outro problema, qual é o erro:? isso você não informou na questão e ai quando fecha vocês reclamam

Comment: Quando acontece isso não da erro, só não gera o pdf, o que eu pedi na questão é alterar o local de salvamento.

Comment: Como eu disse Dirso esse método não tem isso, se tem que fazer pela classe IO responsável (que eu não sei se esse o nome) do python

Comment: Tudo bem. Vou tentar :/

Comment: Exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/123212/6797930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é só você incluir o caminho na definição do nome do arquivo:

```
pdf = canvas.Canvas("C:/Users/seu_usuario/Área de Trabalho/vendas_produtos.pdf")
```

Comment: Obrigado! Tem como eu colocar o local para ser na área de trabalho independente de qual seja o usuário?

Comment: Geralmente a área de trabalho está ligada a um usuário, talvez se você criar uma pasta compartilhada pode ser que resolva, assim todos os usuários teriam acesso ao arquivo.

Comment: Apenas complementando a resposta: você pode pegar a pasta do usuário atual com o método [`Path.home()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home) do módulo `pathlib`. Ex.: `from pathlib import Path; desktop = Path.home() / "Área de Trabalho" / "vendas_produtos.pdf"`.

Answer (score -2):

```
import getpass
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas 
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4

user_windows = getpass.getuser()
cnv = canvas.Canvas(f'C:\\Users\\{user_windows}\\Desktop\\report.pdf', pagesize=A4)
```

veja se te ajuda!